# Codificación JavaMail

Tags: java, codificación

Estoy intentando codificar un Email para enviar con la libreria de JavaMail pero no lo codifica bien, la codificación de la base de datos es `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` y el contenido del Email lo intento codificar asi `message.setContent(htmlContent, "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");` pero no funciona, alguien sabe que puede ser?

Comment: Has probado poniendo charset=UTF8? Si htmlContent es un String, da igual la codificación de la base de datos, puesto que ya fue descodificado por el código que lo extrajo

Comment: Puedes poner lo que te regresa y que es lo que esperas..